# Python Utf-8 writing into CSV

Tags: python, csv, utf-8

I fail to save already encoded data into CSV. I could decode the CSV file afterwards, but I rather do all data cleaning before. I managed to save only text, but when I add timestamp it is impossible.

What I am doing wrong? I read that if `srt()` and `.encode()` is not working and should try `.join` instead, but still nothing

error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

code:

```
def on_data(self, data):
    try:
        #print data
        tweet = data.split(',"text":"')[1].split('","source')[0]

        x = tweet.encode('utf-8')
        y = x.decode('unicode-escape')
        print y

        saveThis = y
        #saveThis = str(time.time())+'::' + tweet.decode('ascii', 'ignore')
        #saveThis = u' '.join((time.time()+'::'+tweet)).encode('utf-8')

        saveFile = open('twitDB.csv', 'a')
        saveFile.write(saveThis)
        saveFile.write('\n')
        saveFile.close()
        return True
    except BaseException, e:
        print 'fail on data,', str(e)
        time.sleep(5) 
def on_error(self, status):
    print status
```

Comment: Why are you manually splitting out JSON data? Use the `json` module instead; e.g. `tweet = json.loads(data)['text']`. This produces a Unicode value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, make sure you handle your JSON data properly, using the [`json` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html).

Next, don't catch `BaseException`, you have no reason to catch memory errors or keyboard interrupts here. Catch more specific exceptions, instead.

Next, encode your data before writing:

```
def on_data(self, data):
    try:
        tweet = json.loads(data)['text']
    except (ValueError, KeyError), e:
        # Not JSON or no text key
        print 'fail on data {}'.format(data)
        return

   with open('twitDB.csv', 'a') as save_file:
        save_file.write(tweet.encode('utf8') + '\n')
        return True
```